# removing whitespace on regex

Tags: reactjs, regex, input-mask

I have this regex

```
^[0-9]{6} [a-zA-Z0-9]{8} [0-9]{6}$
```

It should allow 6 digits followed by a space (automatic, I'm using Inputmask on  test field) 8 alphanumeric followed by 6 digits.

It's working fine but, if we click space bar, it is taking that space also in the place of digits / alphanumerics and it is passing the tests/matches in regex.

How to disable space bar/  whitespace in this expression everywhere(in place of digits & alphanumeric) but not on implemented spacer between space them.

edit: my inputmask if its needed --> `mask="999999 ******** 999999" maskChar=" "`

Comment: Shouldn't `maskChar="*"`?

Comment: No, on input textfield I dont want to display '*' while user is writing in that textbox. i just want that textbox to be empty.